# error while accessing the input from a list

Tags: python-3.x, list

Why does it shows an error if I write

```
for sizes in shoe_sizes:
    if size == sizes:
        print('True')
```

but not when I write

```
if sizes in shoe_sizes:
    print('True')
```

where shoe_sizes is a list containing int

Comment: Please specify what error is showing

Comment: Also send full code. Give example of `size` and `shoe_sizes`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a NameError as 'size' variable is not declared.

Answer (score 0):

```py
if sizes in shoe_sizes:
    print('True')
# This doesn't work because 'sizes' is not a defined variable
```

```py
for sizes in shoe_sizes:
    if size == sizes:
        print('True')
# But this work because for loop defined the variable "sizes" inside shoe-sizes
```

A better way to do this is by using "in" keyword instead of "==" operator without for loop

```
shoe_sizes = [5, 6, 8, 9, 10]
size = 8
if size in shoe_sizes:
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```